# Dividing Decimals in python returns inaccurate results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decimal

```
>>> x = Decimal(1000)
>>> y = Decimal(.005)
>>> x * y
Decimal('5.000000000000000104083408559')
```

I expected the result to be just 5

```
>>> a = 1000
>>> b = .005
>>> a * b
5.0
```

Above is what I expected.

====

The original intention is to divide a `DecimalField` from Django. Should I convert the `Decimal` value to `float` instead? For me to expect accurate resuls?

Comment: `Decimal(.005)` - you already lost precision by creating the float _before_ you created the Decimal. `Decimal(1000) * Decimal(".005")` -> `Decimal('5.000')`

Comment: .005 is a float literal, `decimal.Decimal(0.005)` is
`Decimal('0.005000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875')` but `decimal.Decimal("0.005")` is `Decimal('0.005')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as a string:

```
>>> x = Decimal(1000)
>>> y = Decimal(".005")
>>> x * y
Decimal('5.000')
```

The issue is converting some floats into decimal. Starting with a string wouldn't be an issue.

---

As for your question: you should do the operations on a `Decimal` for it to be accurate.